# parameter being lossed when passed to array_filter

Tags: php

```
    foreach( $items as $item) {
    $taskid = (int) $goal['goal_id'];
    $items[$i]['tasks'] = array();
    $items[$i]['tasks'] = array_filter($tasks, function($task, $taskid){    
    return $task['task_id'] == $taskid;
    });
```

Why is $taskid not being passed to the array_filter function, it returns null if echoed from within but if echoed just after it is set it gives the correct value e.g.

```
    foreach( $items as $item) {
    $taskid = (int) $goal['goal_id'];
    echo $taskid;
```

Will return whatever the integer is

The return part of the function also works if I manually set a value i.e

```
    return $task['task_id'] == 2;
```

Guidance appreciated

Comment: Where do you set $tasks?

Comment: $tasks is an array set earlier, it is fine I can dump ti and interact with it. If I use
return $task['task_id'] == 2;
it all works fine.

Comment: but when I do :-
echo $taskid;
return $task['task_id'] == $taskid; 
$taskid is empty

Answer (score 5):

The issue is variable scope and  function arguments.

First, array_filter expects a function with a single argument, that argument is the value in the position in the array.  It doesn't handle keys.

You set `$taskid = (int) $goal['goal_id'];` outside of the anonymous function, and you have a local variable of the same name, which is null because array_filter only passes one argument.

```
foreach( $items as $item) {
  $taskid = (int) $goal['goal_id'];
  $items[$i]['tasks'] = array();
  # Per the OP, you can pass the necessary variable in via 'use'
  $items[$i]['tasks'] = array_filter($tasks, function($task) use($taskid){
    return $task['task_id'] == $taskid;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guy once you pointed out it was vairiable scope and anonymous functions it was easy enough to fix by referencing in function closure.

```
    $items[$i]['tasks'] = array_filter($tasks, function($task) use(&taskid){    
    return $task['task_id'] == $taskid;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) function passes in an arrays values into a callback function one-by-one. You cannot pass other parameters in with the anonymous callback function like you are attempting to do.

A valid example would be:

```
$array = ["Bob","Sam","Jack"];
print_r(
    array_filter(
        $array, 
        function($value) { 
            return ($value !== 'Jack'); 
        }
    )
);
```

Returns

```
Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => Sam )
```